# Loading specific markers by checkbox?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am loading markers from a database to display on a google map by this below. This is working fine however, I would like to implement the option of pressing a particular button somewhere else on the page, and then map would dynamically change to only show markers pertaining to what was clicked.

Basically, I would like to filter by the 'type' column in my database but still keep all types loaing by default. eg. Page loads, Map loads and displays all types, User clicks on a button which causes the map to only show markers that have type1 as the value in the db. Kind of like a toggle with a check box.

Any ideas of how to go ahead with this, I don't think reloading markers from the db is the most efficient way, can I simply just hide markers which have this property?

```
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("google_map"), googleMapOptions);         

    //Load Markers from the XML File, Check (map_process.php)
    $.get("map_process.php", function (data) {
        $(data).find("marker").each(function () {
              var name      = $(this).attr('name');
              var address   = '<p>'+ $(this).attr('address') +'</p>';
              var type      = $(this).attr('type');
              var description ='<p>'+ $(this).attr('description') +'</p>';
              var point     = new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat($(this).attr('lat')),parseFloat($(this).attr('lng')));
              var icon1 = customIcons[type] || {};

              create_marker(point, name, address, false, false, false, icon1.icon);//"http://sanwebe.com/assets/google-map-save-markers-db/icons/pin_blue.png");
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't just hide some specific markers according to their tag or type, you have to hide/remove them all first and then add those that you need on your map

Here are the functions that you need:

```
var all_markers = [];
var show_markers = [];

function setMarkers(map) {
  for (var i = 0; i < show_markers.length; i++) {
    show_markers[i].setMap(map);
  }
}

function showMarkers(type) {
  setMarkers(null);
  show_markers = []
  for (var i = 0; i < all_markers.length; i++) {
    if (all_markers[i].type == type){
        show_markers.push(all_markers[i])
    }
  }
  setMarkers(map);
}
```

Here is the idea: Load all your markers into the `all_markers`, on your first loading the markers `show_markers` must be equal to `all_markers`. Hitting the button for showing specific markers must trigger function `showMarkers` which will clear your map and reload just specific ones.